# TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, Using Imputer for NaN values

Tags: python, nan

I'm a newbie in python and pandas . I'm trying to preprocess a big dataframe which consists of both numerical and categorical features and in some columns there are NaN values . 
first I try to get the feature matrix and then use Imputer to put the mean or median value for Nan values .

this is the dataframe

```
    MSSubClass MSZoning  LotFrontage  LotArea Street LotShape LandContour  \
0             60       RL         65.0     8450   Pave      Reg         Lvl   
1             20       RL         80.0     9600   Pave      Reg         Lvl   
2             60       RL         68.0    11250   Pave      IR1         Lvl   
3             70       RL         60.0     9550   Pave      IR1         Lvl   
4             60       RL         84.0    14260   Pave      IR1         Lvl   
5             50       RL         85.0    14115   Pave      IR1         Lvl   
6             20       RL         75.0    10084   Pave      Reg         Lvl   
7             60       RL          NaN    10382   Pave      IR1         Lvl   
8             50       RM         51.0     6120   Pave      Reg         Lvl   
9            190       RL         50.0     7420   Pave      Reg         Lvl   
10            20       RL         70.0    11200   Pave      Reg         Lvl   
11            60       RL         85.0    11924   Pave      IR1         Lvl
```

code : just to change the Nan values in LotFrontage (index number = 2) to mean value of the column

```
imputer = Imputer(missing_values='Nan',strategy="mean",axis=0)
features = reduced_data.iloc[:,:-1].values
imputer.fit(features[:,2])
```

when I run this , an error occurs which says :

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

first : Is my approach correct ? 
second : How to handle the Error ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Note the difference between Nan and **NaN** (note the capital N at the end) you have used **Nan**

```
  imputer = Imputer(missing_values='NaN',strategy="mean",axis=0)
```

Replace 'Nan' with 'NaN' and you won't get this error

Answer (score 1):

Try this it is an example of working code

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imputer = Imputer(missing_values = np.nan, strategy = 'mean', axis =0)
imputer = imputer.fit(X[:,1:3])
X[:,1:3] = imputer.transform(X[:,1:3])
```

Comment: now, `from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer`

Answer (score 0):

I guess that due to string 'Nan',your LotFrontage columns data is stored as object data type.Find out using this.It will give object/string most probably.

```
print(reduced_data.LotFrontage.values.dtype)
```

Imputer only works on Floats.

**1st Approach:**

You can do below:
1) Convert column type to Float
2) findout mean of column LotFrontage 
3) Use pandas dataframe function fillna to fill NANs in Dataframe.

```
reduced_data.LotFrontage = pd.to_numeric(reduced_data.LotFrontage, errors='coerce')
m = reduced_data.LotFrontage.mean(skipna=True)
reduced_data.fillna(m)
```

Above code will fillna in Dataframe wherever NANs are present.

**2nd Approach:**

```
reduced_data.LotFrontage = pd.to_numeric(reduced_data.LotFrontage, errors='coerce')
imputer = Imputer()
features = reduced_data.iloc[:,:-1].values
imputer.fit(features[:,2])
```

Answer (score 0):

In missing_value parameter use 'NaN' instead of 'Nan'  :    `imputer=Imputer(missing_values='NaN' ,strategy='mean',axis=0)`

Answer (score 0):

**This should work**

```
imputer = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', axis=0)
imputer = imputer.fit(df.iloc[:, 2:3])
```

Comment: While this may work, it's best to include a description as well.